# RJS method outputting raw javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rjs

I've got a page where I'm dynamically adding elements to a  from a series of select boxes. I'm using RJS to do this and it's working great. Now, these elements in the div are a series of  that are accompanied by Delete buttons, in case the user wants to remove a textarea. Here's where I'm hitting a wall.

Here's the code that runs the Delete button. This is working well to my knowledge:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("/images/button_delete.gif", :alt=>"Delete"), :controller=>"report", :action=>"remove", :id=>@sentence.id %>
```

In my report controller, I've got this very simple method being called by the above code:

def remove
   @sentence_id = params[:id]
end

Again, I think that's working. Now, when I activate this action by hitting the button, off we go to the RJS file, remove.rjs:

```
page.remove 'sentence_'+@sentence_id
```

And here's what I get in my browser, instead of a happily removed element!

```
try 
{
     Element.remove("sentence_63");
} 
catch (e) 
{ 
     alert('RJS error:\n\n' + e.toString()); 
     alert('Element.remove(\"sentence_63\");'); 
     throw e; 
}
```

My understanding is that this happens when there's no page in the current context. Online documentation on this is kind of thin.

Any help appreciated!
Cheers,
Aaron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `remove` function doesn't seem to actually delete a record, if you just want to remove an HTML element from a page you can use `link_to_function` with the Prototype [`remove()` method](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/remove) for Elements. In addition, if you've got a recent version of Rails (for example, 2.3.2) you can take advantage of the [`dom_id` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RecordIdentificationHelper.html#M001606) to auto generate the `sentance_id` ID attribute

`<%= link_to_function(image_tag("button_delete.gif", :alt=>"Delete"), "$('#{dom_id(@sentence}').remove();" %>`

An approach like this could help keep the number of methods down in your controller (unless you intend on doing something else in the controller)

Answer (score 1):

Try link to remote. That will build the ajax call for you and should remove the element from the page.

Then link_to_remote syntax is slightly different than the link_to syntax, so don't let that trip you up either.

Answer (score 0):

Your Delete link is setup as a normal link, i.e.

```
<a href="/report/remove" id="sentence_63">
  <img src="/images/button_delete.gif" alt="Delete" />
</a>
```

which triggers a normal HTTP request. Since your intent is to trigger an AJAX request, try PJ Davis' recommendation and use [`link_to_remote`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M001613)